# Подчеркивание гиперссылки при наведении без использования :hover в вёрстке писем Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

Верстаю письмо для email рассылки. В качестве почтового клиента используется Outlook. В нем недоступны псевдо-классы и многие теги и стили. Совсем нет идей, как я могу сделать подчеркивание гиперссылки при наведении без использования :hover...

```
<a href="#">Какой-то текст</a>
```

Comment: Никак. Магии не существует.

Comment: Предположу, что они недоступны по той причине, что `Outlook` использует внутри себя через `OLE`  браузер `Internet Explorer` в котором дофига чего нет.  Попробуйте версию `Outlook` посвежее - возможно в более новых версиях  уже используется `Edge` который построен на движке `Chromium` где уже есть псевдоклассы. Также, как вариант можете  попробовать делать это через `javascript`